# Scrapy diferentes paginas

Tags: scrapy

Mas estou enfrentando um problema. E acabei me confundindo, resolvi voltar o código num ponto funcional.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# coding: utf-8
import scrapy
from mbu2.items import Mbu2Item2
import urlparse
from scrapy.http import Request

class Spider2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider2"
    # allowed_domains = [""]
    start_urls = (
        # 'file:///C:/scrapy/mbu/mbu2/video.html',
        'file:///C:/scrapy/mbu/mbu2/list.htm',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        # filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        # with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            # f.write(response.body)

        # item = Mbu2Item()
        # return item


        posts = response.xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li')
        posts.pop(0)
        for post in posts:
            print(post)
            item = Mbu2Item2()
            item['currentitemlist'] = response.url
            item['currentitemlink'] = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,post.xpath('div/div/h2/a/@href').extract()[0].strip())
            item['posttitle'] = post.xpath('div/div/h2/a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            # print(item['posttitle'])
            item['posturl'] = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,post.xpath('div/div/h2/a/@href').extract()[0].strip())
            item['postautor'] = post.xpath('div/div/div/div[1]/a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            # print(item['postautorurl'])
            item['postautorurl'] = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,post.xpath('div/div/div/div[1]/a/@href').extract()[0].strip())
            item['postcat'] = post.xpath('div/div/div/div[2]/span/a/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            # print(item['postcaturl'])
            item['postcaturl'] = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,post.xpath('div/div/div/div[2]/span/a/@href').extract()[0].strip())
            # print(item['posttitle'], item['posturl'], item['postautor'], item['postautorurl'])[0].strip()
            # request = Request(item['posturl'],
                      # callback=self.parse_page2)

            # request.meta['item'] = item
            return Request(item['posturl'], meta={'item': item},
                      callback=self.parse_item)
            # return item


    def parse_item(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['currentitemlink2'] = response.url
        # item['desc'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['videosrcembed'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/article/iframe/@src').extract()[0].strip()
        item['textcontent'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[1]').extract()[0].strip()
        item['relatedcatlinks'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[2]').extract()[0].strip()
        # filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        # with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            # f.write(response.body)

        yield item
```

**Problema Principal**

Quando rodo o spider. Ele registra apenas 1 item.

Realizei as modificações na lógica, dai ele registrou 25 itens, mas não completou com o segundo Request.

(Eu preciso adicionar novos requests a cada listagem lida, add->start_page->append(new_url)

Mas não estou sabendo identificar quando ele fecha o ciclo de um Item() e quando ele está realizando o parse de uma listagem.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Faça isto ir para uma variável e a verifique: `return Request(item['posturl'], meta={'item': item},
                      callback=self.parse_item)`. Qual o valor dela? Depois pode retorná-la normalmente.

Comment: Dica: em vez de `urlparse.urljoin(response.url, XYZ)` vc pode fazer `response.urljoin(XYZ)` :)

Comment: eu realizei isto aqui ontem: request = Request.... \n print(request). Eu vi os dados, mas veio faltando 3 campos que é realizado no parse_item. Seria esta a duvida?

Comment: Criei um outro scrapyprojet, fiz um spider simples, e pra minha surpresa funcionou. http://codepad.org/e1dbzj39

Comment: Pessoal, consegui. Acredito que o problema foi porque usei Request(Static_file, callback=parse2), por isso ele só aceitava 1 item. Faz sentido?

Comment: Minha lista esta sendo processada, mas preciso que ele continue processando mais start_pages(categorias). Criei uma outra pergunta aqui com algumas duvidas pra fechar.. http://tinyurl.com/z88y3fu se puderem olhar.. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Substitua o `return` do método `parse` por um `yield`.

O `return` está causando o método retornar no primeiro caso, sem terminar de percorrer o restante dos posts no laço for.

Usando `yield` você transformará a função em um [gerador](http://www.slideshare.net/ramalho/iteraveis-e-geradores-em-python), que o Scrapy irá percorrer e processar o resultado apropriadamente.

Comment: então, eu fiz usando o yield dps passei pro return, tentei return dps do yield mas gera um erro. Eu fiz muitos testes e não consegui compreender como é formado a lista. Voltei o yield. Eu faço um print(post) dentro do loop. Na tela vejo que ele passou por 25 itens. Mas só armazenou 1. 

2016-07-13 12:59:57 [scrapy] INFO: Stored json feed (1 items) in: out.json
 'dupefilter/filtered': 24, O que significa este duperfilter?

Comment: Ah, dupefilter/filtered são requests que estão sendo filtradas porque estão sendo iguais as anteriores (ou seja, `item['posturl']` tava dando sempre o mesmo resultado). Fiquei achando que era um problema nas XPaths. Eu tentaria modificar os XPaths de dentro do loop para usar `./` no começo, tipo: `post.xpath('./div/div/h2/a/@href')`